# Is there a difference between modulo groups with and without asterisks ($\mathbb{Z}_{38}$ vs $\mathbb{Z}_{38}^*$)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, notation, modular-arithmetic

I know modulo group $\mathbb{Z}_{38}$ but I saw it with a star in some question: $\mathbb{Z}_{38}^*$. Is it is the same as $\mathbb{Z}_{38}$ or a different group? If it refers to the same group does star matter in any way?

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb Z_{38}$ is the *additive* group of integers modulo $38$.

$\mathbb Z_{38}^{\times}$ is the *multiplicative* group of integers modulo $38$. Its elements are the classes of numbers that are coprime with $38$.

Comment: okay..thanks, i knew the notation u(38)

Comment: @AbhishekChandra, yes, $U(38)$ is also a popular notation.

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbb{Z}_{n}^{*}$ in general refers to the multiplicative group modulo n. This is the set of elements that don't share any common factors with $n$ other than $1$. Example:

$$\mathbb{Z}_{4} = \lbrace 0,1,2,3 \rbrace $$
$$\mathbb{Z}_{4}^* = \lbrace 1,3 \rbrace \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$$

Comment: Your welcome! Feel free to upvote if you find something useful, and accept at least one of the answers if they answer your question.